# Create custom search in SharePoint 2013 with OOTB features

Tags: search, search-results, search-scope

Can any one please tell me the steps to create a custom search in sharepoint 2013 using OOTB features? I also want to know few more things.

- How to search only documents?
- How to search only lists?
- How to filter author and date?

Answer (score 1):

There is an OOTB result sources called Documents, you can use that to limit the results to documents.

For lists, create a result source with query like this: `{searchTerms}contentclass:STS_List`

For list items, create a result source with query like this: `{searchTerms}contentclass:STS_ListItem`

Check this article: http://techmikael.blogspot.in/2013/04/limiting-search-results-in-sharepoint.html

To filter by author and date, use the Refinement Panel web part. Add the two managed properties to the Refinement Panel web part.